# In-call status bar pushes UIPageViewController content view down

Tags: ios, statusbar, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a UIPageViewController. When the in-call status bar is toggled while in this view, it adjusts fine. If the in-call status bar is open before the UIPageViewController is loaded, the page gets pushed down by 20pt and a black bar is shown in that space.

Here's a screenshot of what this looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Other posts recommend using setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on the page controller to NO. I've already tried that and it does not work. I've also tried `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Setting the origin of the UIPageViewController frame to 0 works, but feels wrong:

```
CGRect frame = self.pageController.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = 0;
self.pageController.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Did you find any possible solution for this? I am experiencing a very similar issue with the status bar as you have laid out here.

Comment: The code snippet I included to set the y origin of the page controller's frame to 0 works for me. Put it in you UIPageViewController's `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by ensuring the right constraints were on my view controller's main view. Here is an example where I am adding a view controller's view as a subview to a root view controller and then using Masonry (https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to establish constraints that will snap all the child view controller's main view's edges to the root view controller (which itself already has autoresizing masks in place from Interface Builder). This resolved my issue of the status bar leaving that black space because it was pushing this view down (rather than re-sizing):

```
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController.view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

In your case, and I don't have your full code so I don't know for sure but something like:

```
[self.pageController.view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.pageController.view.superview);
}];
```

.. ought to do the trick.

Comment: Yep that works! There is a typo in the code, it should be `make.edges.equalTo(self.pageController.view.superview);`
I noticed that when the in-call status bar is triggered the animation to move the child view down is a bit janky. Do you see that as well?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer (be sure to up-vote my answer, too!). I do see the slight jankiness but don't know a better way around it (possibly thinking through it further and doing an animation to re-size might be smoother). But at least this gets away from the fugly black bar issue left from not re-sizing.

Comment: Yep, 100% agree it's better than the black bar:) Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Thanks,this answer help me